# How do I test if my video card is starting to fail?

Tags: graphics-card

I'm having some issues with my PC rendering images. Sometimes the screen shows only half of the picture and sometimes it shows lines all over the screen.

This happens after waking the computer from sleep.

Are there specific tests that can show if my graphic card is failing? A test similar to memory tests?

Comment: There are none that I know of. The best way to be sure is swap the card e.g. with an old one if you can.

Comment: Not precisely duplicates of either question, but the answer is to stress test GPU and VRAM.

Answer (score 1):

Graphical weirdness after waking from sleep sounds like a driver issue, or other wonky software.

Still, Here's a link to some GPU test software: [MemtestG80, and MemtestCL](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/DownloadUtils) that may or may not work in your case (MemtestG80 is Nvidia specific, though MemtestCL is not but has it's own requirements). Linux, Windows and OSX variants.